# How to remove charset=utf-8 from the response header content type

Tags: apache, utf-8, response-headers

How to use apache AddType to map "text/css;charset=utf-8" to "text/css". So that the response header will look like.

In the response header:

From - Content-Type: text/css;charset=utf-8
To - Content-Type: text/css

I need to remove charset=utf-8 from the response header using AddType in apache.

Comment: [`RemoveCharset` directive?](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#removecharset)

Comment: On loading the page the css files are getting the response header as Content-Type: text/css;charset=utf-8. I want to remove charset=utf-8. Is there any way this can be achieved using apache AddType?

Comment: which charset are your CSS files encoded in? Does it make a difference if it's declared or not?

Comment: I have included it to the html. I don't want it to be specific to the css.

Comment: Your question is too generic. The first comment gives you some hints. Apache do not add Content-Type by default (but most distribution activate mod-mime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the original charset was added.

As @JoopEggen correctly said, `RemoveCharset` can undo the effects of character set associations for given extensions.

Another case is when the charset was specified in the configuration file by, say, `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`. Then you can undo this in  your `.htaccess` with `AddDefaultCharset off`.